# Fetching from rest api vue

Tags: vue.js, async-await, fetch, undefined

I am probably kinda stupid :) But i have copy pasted a couple of hundreed solutions noee and tried everything i can think of (i am totally newe to VUE and JS so please be kind:) )

This is thee code i have right now. I can see that it fetches the data in F12 but i cant get the data into a variable that i can use outside my function.

I want to do kinda reponseDataToSession.user.name and so on on my data or loop through some of the data but if i console.log outside my fetch i get empty or nothing.

Please help me get my code working spent all day on this little thingy.

The error i get is : ReferenceError: reponseDataToSession is not defined

So here is the code.

```
 <template>
    <div id="app">
        <input
                v-model="sessionUUID"
                @keyup.enter="fetchsessions()"
                name="search"
                type="text"
        />

        <input
                @mouseup="fetchsessions()"
                name="serchSubmit"
                value="SÖK"
                type="submit"
        />

        <template v-if="viewData">
            {{responseDataToSession}}
        </template>
    </div>
</template>


<script>
import base64 from "base-64";

export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      sessionUUID: "",
        responseDataToSession: {},
      viewData: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    fetchsessions: function () {
      const url = "http://localhost:8080/gethistory";
      const method = "POST"
      const username = "user";
      const password = "bass";
      const body = JSON.stringify({"uuid": "' + this.sessionUUID + '","answers": []});       
      const headers = new Headers();

      headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
      headers.append("Authorization", "Basic " + base64.encode(username + ":" + password));
      
      this.responseDataToSession = fetching();
      console.log("1"+this.reponseDataToSession)
      this.viewData = true

      async function fetching() {
        return this.responseDataToSession = await fetch(url, { method, headers, body });
      }

    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: `console.log(reponseDataToSession.sessionSteeps)` should be `console.log(this.reponseDataToSession.sessionSteeps)`

Comment: Unrelated: `reponseDataToSession` is not initialized correctly in `data()`

Comment: Change the console.log and now i get Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: response is not defined.
And about initialization pleas tell me how to do instead, like i said i'm new to all this.

Answer (score 0):

You have an `ReferenceError: response is not defined` because your have to declare your variable response before. So you should write :

```
async function fetching() {
        const  response = await fetch(url, { method, headers, body });
        return response
      }
```

or maybe directly (if your variable "response" is just for your function you dont' need it)

```
async function fetching() {
        return await fetch(url, { method, headers, body });
      }
```

For  the `responseDataToSession` , try with `responseDataToSession: {}` ,

Comment: Updated code a bit. Now i get in console undefined.
And if i in my html write it out as above i get [object Promise]
Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try    `this.responseDataToSession = await fetch(url, { method, headers, body });` and  `const body = JSON.stringify({"uuid": "' + this.sessionUUID + '","answers": []}}; ` ??

Comment: No, in your code, replace      `const body = '{"uuid": "' + this.sessionUUID + '","answers": []}';` by `const body = JSON.stringify({"uuid": "' + this.sessionUUID + '","answers": []}}; ` then replace `this.responseDataToSession = fetching();` by `this.responseDataToSession = await fetch(url, { method, headers, body });`

Comment: Updated code above.
Now it types out 1undefined in consol but no errors atleast :)
And html types out [object Promise]

Comment: can you add a  `console.logs(headers)` after       `headers.append("Authorization", "Basic " + base64.encode(username + ":" + password)); ` . I would like to see the value of `header`. Show me the response of the console

Comment: Solved it with the help off a coworker now :)

Thanks för all the help and your time.

Tried to paste the code in a new answer but i am no allowed now :(